# is there a way to sort data from an imput value

Tags: excel, vba

i have 3 columns in excel with the values Name / City / Birthday i try to create an inputbox where i can type in the Name and a second one where i will type in the birth date so that the result that will show up in the 'th column will be City+Birthday only for the name used in the first imputbox.
i tried this but it didn't work

```
Sub fill_next()
    For i = 2 To 10
        If InputBox("vam", "val") = Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Range("E" & i).Value = Range("B" & i) & InputBox("enter number", "value baliz")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `Range("B" & i) & InputBox(...)` supposed to return? That's not going to return a valid range, and I bet is an issue that will throw an error.

Comment: You need to capture the first Inputbox into a variable before you start the loop, or it will prompt for every iteration.

Comment: To reconfirm - you have two inputboxes, and you want the result to be returned in which column? ('th column - what is that?). Can you show a snapshot of the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range("B" & i) contained a dropdown list and InputBox(...) a variable that is added to the text i solved the problem

the isue was in Range("B" & i) the dropdown list wasn't detected and i specified the cells in the code. thanks everyone

```
Sub fill_next()
For i = 1 To 8
If Range("A" & 15).Value = Range("A" & i).Value Then

Range("A" & 21).Value = Range("B" & 15) & "*" & InputBox("enter restaure date",      "Consultation") & "*""" & Range("C" & 15).Value
End If
Next i
End Sub
```